# retreiving recently updated SQL records in php

Tags: php, select, insert

Is it possible to update the database and then fetch a new recordset right after that will have all this new data entered? Do I need some kind of closure to make sure the insert sql has completed before doing a new SELECT that will contain all the new records?

Ie, put simply, if I have 50 000 entries in total with a structure like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `acc_change`(`ID`, `type`, `name`, `amount`, `date`, `processed`) 

VALUES (NULL, 'auto', 'Lorem', '75.00', '2018-04-05 00:00:00', 'no'),
(NULL, 'auto', 'Ipsum', '12.00', '2018-04-25 00:00:00', 'no'),(NULL, 'auto', 'Dolor', '24.00', '2018-04-28 00:00:00', 'no')...

INSERT INTO `videos`(`ID`, `type`, `name`, `date`, `processed`) 

VALUES (NULL, 'auto', 'Lorem', '2018-04-05 00:00:00', 'no')...
```

Will I then be able to do something like this:

```
$update_sql = "SELECT * FROM `acc_change` where `date` < '2018-04-23 12:32:00'"
$sqlMsg = enterSql($update_sql);
```

and get all the recently added records?

**IMPORTANT:** 
Normally I'd:

1. pull old data from the database and save it in arrays/objects
2. pull the new data and save in arrays/objects.
3. filter out what I need and make new arrays/objects.
4. create new insert SQL statements.

I am perfectly aware that this is a sollution to the problem, but that is NOT what I am asking. I am asking if/how you can insert/update and then access that new data right away.

My database functions:

```
function db($action){
    static $conn;
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "life2020";
    if ($action == "use"){
        if ($conn === null){ 
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
            if (!$conn) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
        }
        return $conn;
    } else {
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}

function get_db_rows($sql){
    $rows = array();
    $conn = db("use");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Erro!: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return $rows;
}

function enterSql($sql){
    $sqlMsg = "";
    $conn = db("use");
    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $sqlMsg = "Entered data";
    } else {
        $sqlMsg = "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    return $sqlMsg;
}
```

Comment: `I am asking if/how you can insert/update and then access that new data right away.` Well, [insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) will return `0` or `The value of the AUTO_INCREMENT field that was updated by the previous query`. However, that's only with `INSERT` queries.. You could get your `enterSql` to equal`insert_id` instead of `"Entered data"` as `Error updating record` will enumerate to `0` if you wanted to run a number check (`if(enterSql($sql) > 0)`)

Comment: Oh, ok - so I could check for insert_id in a loop and then sleep() if it’s not done yet? I like it.

Comment: How would you deal with updates though?

Comment: There's no need to `sleep()` at all because `mysqli_query` will hang until it is finished executing the query. To handle `UPDATE` you should probably pass around the `ID` that you use as the unique identifier in the query

Comment: Yes, I loved that about mysqli_query - but it would seem that mysqli_multi_query which I’m using doesn’t do that.

Comment: Essentially what I need is to know when mysqli_multi_query is done executing

Comment: `mysqli_multi_query` does hang until it has finished executing.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC,LIMIT 2.